# Encode edge style parameters with variable argument count in \foreach list

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, edge

In Ti*k*Z there is the `\foreach` construct which one can use to iterate over a list of items and draw them as desired.

Is it possible to encode, say, edge style parameters in the list like so (which unfortunately gives a Runaway Argument error):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{
      sty1/.style args={#1:#2}{postaction=decorate,decoration={name=markings, mark=at position #1 with {\draw (0,0) -- (1,1) node {#2}; }}},
      sty2/.style args={#1:#2:#3}{postaction=decorate,decoration={name=markings, mark=at position #1 with {\draw (0,0) -- node {#3} (1,1) node {#2}; }}}
    }

    % option 1
    \foreach \a/\b in {sty1/.7:AParam2, sty2/.7:AParam2:AParam3, sty1/.7:AParam2, sty2/.7:AParam2:AParam3}{
        \path (0,0) edge[\a=\b] (1,1);
    }

    % option 2 - the preferred option because I need the number at different independent places
    \foreach \a/\b in {1/.7:AParam2, 2/.7:AParam2:AParam3, 1/.7:AParam2, 2/.7:AParam2:AParam3}{
        \path (0,0) edge[sty\a=\b] (1,1);
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see the corresponding style of a list item determines the number of arguments that are given to the style.

Is there maybe a royal road to encode style parameters with a variable argument count in the `\foreach` list?

---

What I'm trying to do is to mark edges with a variable number of lines of different color. I want to define the number of lines and colors in the `\foreach` list along with other parameters for each edge, e.g., the text in an annotation node, in and out angles and stuff like that.

Comment: Since you're using the style inside the `\foreach` (which has only one `\path`) why not use the style explicitly written inside `edge`? Like in `\path (0,0) edge[postaction=decorate,decoration={name=markings, mark=at position {\a} with {\draw (0,0) -- (1,1) node {\b};}}] (1,1);`?

Comment: That's because the `\foreach` in my actual document does not contain only the `\path` element. This is just an MWE that ought to show what I'm after. Aside from the `\path` the `\foreach` contains nodes that get placed in along an arc around another node. That's why I'm using a `\foreach`. To be able to modify the number of nodes and the styles only by altering the list and not having to add/remove additional TikZ code.

Answer (score 1):

In the OP's code, the styles receive `\b` as the value, while they expect a value of the form `...:...` (`sty1`) and `...:...:...` (`sty2`). This is why the `Runaway argument` error is raised. The solution is to expand the value using handler `.expanded` before passing it to the style, like so:

```
\path (0,0) edge[sty\a/.expanded=\b] (1,1);
```